# regarding javascript call form submit and resume button

Tags: javascript

I was working on a form which has three buttons, one is for submit and other one is for resume and other is reset.Now i want to validate form on submit but not on the resume button click.

my html form.

```
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sur").validate();
    });
    </script>
    <form action="/survey/save/" method="post" name="sur" id="sur">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
<div id="submit"></div>
    <center><div class="submit-button">
        <input type='submit' value='resume' onclick='this.form.action="/resume/save/";' />
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
```

Here resume button doesn't require any validation. How avoid the validation on resume button click

Adding a sample example to play around

http://jsfiddle.net/SXEZP/3/

Any help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only call the validator when the "submit" button is clicked. Don't do anything when "resume" is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.validate-submit').click(function() {
        return $("#sur").form();
    });
});
```

and change your button:

```
<input type="submit" class="validate-submit" value="submit">
```

Validator.form() documentation: http://validation.bassistance.de/Validator.form/